# Opening HTML link in new window

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, onclick

I've got a table that shows details about some products, which are stored in the database. These details are Item Name, Price and submit Date.

```
Item Name   Price   Submitted on
Laptop       £30     12/04/10
guitar       £5      12/05/10
```

If I click on Laptop I want to see all details such as Title, Price, Description, Picture, Contact name and email (all details are stored in the database) in a new windows.

I don't know if a PHP function will do it or maybe I need javascript?? I look on Google but I could find anything.

I hope you undestand my question

Comment: You've been told how to do it. My advice is don't do it. Automatically opening new windows is almost always annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you open a link in a new window.

```
<a href="detailsPage.php?itemID=1234" target="_blank">Name of your Product</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really have anything to do with PHP or MySQL.

Depending on the version of (X)HTML you're using you can either set the target attribute on the link...

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">...</a>
```

...or you can use a JavaScript function that makes use of [window.open](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml).

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in PHP for this as PHP runs on the server end.  You would need to generate the HTML or JavaScript to do this either using the `target="_blank"` attribute on a link, or using JavaScript's window.open, depending on the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need java script or PHP.

This can be achieved by HTML.

`<a href="xyz.php" target="_blank">Product</a>`

target="_blank" is a attribute of <a> tag. Using this link can be opened in new window.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! all answers were very useful!