# How to add target attribute to anchor tag to open hyperlink in a new tab or window?

Tags: php

I have the code below to make part of my rss feed a hyperlink but how to i change this to make the link open in a new tab or a new window.

```
print "<a href=\"$this->link\">";
```

I tried adding `target="_blank"`but was not sure how to add it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening HTML link in new window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468374/opening-html-link-in-new-window)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print "<a href=\"$this->link\" target=\"_blank\">";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print "<a href='$this->link' target='_blank'>";
```